# Help With Joining Minecraft LAN

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My sister and I have been trying to join each other on a LAN Minecraft Bedrock world. She uses a school IPad and I use a regular one. We get on the same network, and we’re friended on Xbox, but it always says “unable to join.”
The weirdest part about it is whenever we’re playing with friends, we’re both always able to join their worlds, but never our own! If one of my friends is on my world, then she can join, but when they aren’t she can’t. It’s super annoying, and if someone has a solution it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

School iPads cannot use LAN play.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Any source for your statement?